# Ram on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, tomcat, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

So I was wondering if there was any way to allow more ram to a program on a Raspberry Pi 3.
I have a process which takes 76,7% of the memory (it's a tomcat server) and need another one like this to run, so my Raspberry can't handle it right now.

Is there a way to run a program using something else as ram or convert virtually a part of the sd card in ram (like on Android for instance). Or can we add physically a ram module ? Or can we force a program to take less memory ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: This is not a programming question. This question should be migrated to https://superuser.com/ or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh thank you, I didn't know these forums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi 3 has 1 GB of RAM, so I suppose it should be capable of running two instances, depending on what exactly your server is doing.

Tomcat itself runs on a JVM (Java virtual machine), so you can configure the amount of memory allocated to it. Try setting the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable to adjust maximum memory usage.

Depending on your setup, you should be able to do this in `/etc/default/tomcat*` (where * depends on your version of Tomcat) by adding a line such as `JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m"`. This example would allocate a maximum of 512 MB to Tomcat.

What you are describing about using the SD card as RAM is called swap memory. Your system does this automatically when it runs out of memory, but it is very slow and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Swap is not used automatically unless previously configured. You need to configure either a swap partition or a swap file. Some distributions do this automatically, others don't.

Comment: It is running an Alfresco instance which is pretty heavy (I'm testing if a Rasp could handle it). I'm going to try to allow less space in my java_opts, i'm currently at 1024 so that may cause this issue. So that's the swap space ! Even if it's slow I think it could be useful, is there a limit to this ? Because htop is telling me it's used at 90%

Comment: There is no limit for swap space, you can use as much as you want. What does `free -m` tell about your current swap usage?

Comment: @scai it says mem : total=923 used=892 free=31 ; +/- buffers/cache : used=746 free=177 ; Swap : total=99 used=59 free=40